# 'if a == b[0]' not working when using readlines() SOLVED

Tags: python, file

I'm writing a Who Wants to Be a Millionare program, but the issue I'm having is that even if the user enters the correct answer, it says it's the wrong answer. I'm new to the whole reading from files thing, so there's probably something I'm missing.

Example output:

```
    What do you think? 3
    That is the wrong answer!
    The right answer was 3

    Thanks for playing!
```

Some of the code below:

```
    questions_file = open('questions.txt', 'r')
questions = questions_file.readlines()
choices_file = open('choices.txt', 'r')
choice = choices_file.readlines()
answers_file = open('answers.txt', 'r')
answers = answers_file.readlines()
prize_file = open('prize.txt', 'r')
prize = prize_file.readlines()

print('Question 1 for',prize[0])
print(questions[0])
print('1 -',choice[0])
print('2 -',choice[1])
print('3 -',choice[2])
print('4 -',choice[3])
answ_1 = int(input('What do you think? '))

if answ_1 == answers[0]:
    print('That is the correct answer!')
else:
    print('That is the wrong answer!')
    print('The right answer was',answers[0])
    print('Thanks for playing!')
    exit()
```

Comment: Hi, I added the python tag to your question so it's easier for people to know which language you're asking about (I assume it's python)

Comment: Add `print(repr(answ_1), repr(answers[0]))` before the compare. `repr` gives more information about object and data than `str` and helps you spot differences between a string and integer as well as newlines that may invalidate your comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make `answ_1` an int (`int(input('What do you think? '))`) but the inputs from the files are string.

Either make `answ_1` simply a string: `answ_1 = input('What do you think? ')` or make the answer an int as well: `if answ_1 == int(answers[0]):`

Comment: Leaving both as strings can still fail if there are hidden newline characters in the string.  Converting user input to `int` can fail badly if the user types something non-numeric.

Comment: The leave as strings option is great as long as newlines are stripped from `answers`.

Comment: I agree, my answer is limited to explaining the reason this issue occurs but does not include any additional validation. I would suggest converting both to an int and catching any `ValueError` but I thought that this might be outside the scope of the question.